# Keyup() delay not firing if new keyup is initiated first

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, keyup

I'm using jquery .keyup() with a delay to trigger form validation. I've set the delay in two parts. One delay is for the keyup function and another delay added to an error response so it's not giving errors unnecessarily if someone is say a slow typer. I don't see it as an issue for success confirmation which is why it is only applied to errors.

The issue here happens when the user types an error in an input and starts typing in the next input before the error delay has triggered. When this happens the ajax validation for the first input does not occur. So what's a solution to make this work correctly?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var delay = (function(){
      var timer = 0;
      return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
      };
    })();
    var j=jQuery;
    j('.prompt-cont input').on('keyup', function(){
     $anchor = j(this);
     delay(function(){
      var valtype = $anchor.data("type");
      var fieldval = $anchor.val();
      var pass = j("input#signup_password").val();
      var conpass = j("input#signup_password_confirm").val();
      j.post( ajaxurl, {
         action: 'valregister_fields',
         'cookie': encodeURIComponent(document.cookie),
         'fieldval':fieldval,
         'passval':pass,
         'passvalcom':conpass,
         'valtype':valtype
      },
      function(response){
         var resp=JSON.parse(response);
         if(resp.code=='success') {
           $target=$anchor.closest(".prompt-cont");
           $target.find(".val-error").remove();
           $target.find(".val-error-ajax").fadeOut().empty();
           $target.find(".val-color").removeClass('error').addClass('success').fadeIn();
         } else if(resp.code=='error'|| resp.code=='taken' || resp.code=='registered') {
         // } else if (j.inArray(resp.code, ['error', 'taken', 'registered'])) {
          delay(function(){
           $target=$anchor.closest(".prompt-cont");
           $target.find(".val-color").fadeOut().removeClass('success').addClass('error').fadeIn();
           $target.find(".val-error").remove();
           $target.find(".prompt").effect( "shake", { times:3 }, 500 );
           $target.find(".val-error-ajax").empty().fadeOut().html(resp.message).fadeIn();
         }, 1000 );
         } else {
           $target=$anchor.parent("#ajax_check")
           $target.find(".error").remove();
           $target.find("#name-info").removeClass();
           $target.find("#name-info").empty().html(resp.message);
         }
      });
     }, 200 );
    });
});
```

Comment: why are you using delay to check the amount of key strokes.......trigger the error check mechanism only when there are certain amount of characters in the input using $('#inputfield').val().length === 'limit'..

Comment: why not simply use `blur`?

Comment: I wasn't being clear. What I mean is I add a longer delay so errors aren't triggering if someone is a slow typer for instance or pauses for a split second. What I need is for that error to fire no matter whether the user has started typing in a new input or not.

Comment: I don't use blur because the last field doesn't get validated that way since the next logical click is the submit button.